# Get documents inserted this and last hour

Tags: php, mongodb

I just switched to mongoDB from MySQL and I have been trying to count documents inserted this hour and last hour, I searched everywhere but couldn't find anything about it. Someone please help.

Comment: Can you share your database structure? What have you attempted so far?

Answer (score 0):

Query

- `$$NOW` has the current date of the server, if you want your client time use a PHP variable for the date.
- subtracting the dates => difference in milliseconds
- and filter this difference to be `[0,2]` hours
- and then group by null, so all collection 1 group, and count them

*`lastModified` is a random field name that has the Date
*this is dates difference query in milliseconds, not calendar one

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match": 
    {"$expr": 
      {"$lte": 
        [{"$subtract": ["$$NOW", "$lastModified"]},
          {"$multiply": [2, 60, 60, 1000]}]}}},
  {"$group": {"_id": null, "count": {"$count": {}}}}])
```